# jQuery stopping url click in div attached to function

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I've got a div set out like this

```
<div class="clickformore">
  <h3>Business in<br>action</h3>
  <div class="foundoutmore">
    <div class="uparrow"></div>
    <div class="underarrow">
      <p>Develop critical and problem solving skills faculties by investigating challenges faced by business leaders and to practice the skills to devise and implement practical solutions.<br><a href="http://www.ncl.ac.uk/postgraduate/modules/module/NBS8490/" target="_blank">http://www.ncl.ac.uk/postgraduate/modules/module/NBS8490/</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and where only the h3 is visible and everything else is hidden. jQuery which shows the found out more div which has the arrow and textbox making it look like a speech bubble.

But when a user would click on the link in the hidden div when shown it hides again, without opening the link.

```
$(".clickformore").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find(".foundoutmore").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
        $(this).find(".foundoutmore").css("display","inherit");
    } else {
        $(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

I've tried aiming at the link with css doing a z-index hoping it would first be clickable before the div hid to no avail, I tried to figure out a way to make the showing div not hide it again but I can't figure that out and end of a tether.

Is there a way I can make the link clickable before the div hides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this bro ..

```
$(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
$("h3").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).next().css('display')=='none'){
        $(this).next().css("display","inherit");
    } else {
        $(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/sLwqgdp2/)

Comment: This worked, thank you. 
I added to this because I have more than one clickformore and I needed clicking on a new one to hide all of the rest rather than leaving them open.

`$("h3").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(this).next().css('display')=='none'){
  $(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
  $(this).next().css("display","inherit");
 } else {
  $(".foundoutmore").css("display","none");
 }
});`

(Apparently I have no idea how this styling thing works on this site, go figure)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="clickformore">

    <h3>Business in<br>action</h3>

    <div class="foundoutmore hidden">
        <div class="uparrow"></div>
        <div class="underarrow">
            <p>Develop critical and problem solving skills faculties by investigating challenges faced by business leaders and to practice the skills to devise and implement practical solutions.
                <br><a href="http://www.ncl.ac.uk/postgraduate/modules/module/NBS8490/" target="_blank">http://www.ncl.ac.uk/postgraduate/modules/module/NBS8490/</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




$(".foundoutmore").hide();
```

or add

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

to your CSS then:

```
$(".clickformore").on('click', 'h3', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var more = $(this).next('.foundoutmore');
    more.toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6j33tmey/1/)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but this didn't work in my code. I'm guessing it must have conflicted with code already there. Thanks anyway!